# Ignore leading whitespace reading from file

Tags: c++

I am trying to read from an input file to my C++ program but am having whitespace issues.

I have an external .txt input file in the format:

```
ABC   DEF
GH   IJK
LMNO PQ
```

Each line contains two "words" and a random amount of whitespace between the first and second "word" on each line. Each line ends with a new line after the second "word".

I am trying to write a function `NextWord()` that I can call on the ifstream and each time it will return the next "word" in the stream until all words in the stream are processed.

My code currently:

```
std::string NextWord(ifstream& inputStream)
{
    string nextWord;
    getline(inputStream, nextWord,' ');
    return nextWord;
}

int main()
{
    string input = "input.txt";
    ifstream inFile(input);  // create ifstream object
    cout << NextWord(inFile) << endl;
    cout << NextWord(inFile) << endl;
    cout << NextWord(inFile) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The issue I clearly have is that I am specifying the delimitor in `getline()` to be a space `' '` which is fine for the first word in each line but then the next time `NextWord()` is called it will return a `' '` again each time until it hits the second "word" in each line.

How do I delimit by whitespace to get the first "word" in each line properly, but then ignore the next leading white spaces between the first and second words in each line so that the output from my program is:

```
ABC
DEF
GH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `getline` in a white space separated file.  `operator >>` will ignore leading white space and stop at the first occurrence of white space so you can use that to read your file like

```
std::string NextWord(ifstream& inputStream)
{
    string nextWord;
    inputStream >> nextWord;
    return nextWord;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `operator>>`, it skips whitespace by design

```
std::string NextWord(ifstream& inputStream)
{
    string nextWord;
    inputStream >> nextWord;
    return nextWord;
}
```